# Subest a dataframe using value pairs in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` called `IncorrectQuestions_df` which looks like this:

[image]

These questions pairs can repeat many, many times in this `DataFrame`. There are a total of about 50 Million records in this `DataFrame`.

I create another `DataFrame` using this the existing one, which calculates the total number of question pairs. Here's the code I used:

```
IncorrectQuestions_count = pd.DataFrame(IncorrectQuestions_df.groupby(['Question1', 'Question2'])
                                    .size()
                                    ,columns=['Count'])
```

Now I wanted to only keep the pairs which occur atleast 5 times, so I subset using the following code:

```
IncorrectQuestions_count = IncorrectQuestions_count[IncorrectQuestions_count['Count'] >= 5]
IncorrectQuestions_count.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

which gives me the following:

[image]

`IncorrectQuestions_count` has about 80,000 pairs. I would like to subset `IncorrectQuestion_df` to only contain the pairs present in `IncorrectQuestions_count`. If I write 2 `for` loops to do this, it will take a large amount of time to finish, so I was wondering if there's a more pythonic way to achieve this?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a merge operation.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'q1':randint(0,3,26),'q2':randint(0,3,26),
'state':[chr(i+ord('a')) for i in range(26)]})

cnts=df.groupby(['q1','q2']).count()>4

df['ok']=df.merge(cnts,left_on=cnts.index.names,right_index=True).state_y
result=df[df.ok]
```

For, on this example:

```
    q1  q2   state      ok
0    2   1       a    True
2    2   1       c    True
9    2   1       j    True
22   2   1       w    True
24   2   1       y    True
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a merge here:

```
# define min count
min_count = 2

# setup dummy data
columns = ["Question 1", "Question 2"]
data = [["Q1", "Q2"],
        ["Q1", "Q2"],
        ["Q1", "Q2"],
        ["Q3", "Q4"],
        ["Q3", "Q4"],
        ["Q1", "Q4"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)

  Question 1 Question 2
0         Q1         Q2
1         Q1         Q2
2         Q1         Q2
3         Q3         Q4
4         Q3         Q4
5         Q1         Q4

# get counts
counts = df.groupby(columns).size()
counts = counts[counts >= min_count].reset_index().rename(columns={0:"Counts"})

# final merge
subset = pd.merge(df, counts, on=columns, how="right")

print(subset)

  Question 1 Question 2  Counts
0         Q1         Q2       3
1         Q1         Q2       3
2         Q1         Q2       3
3         Q3         Q4       2
4         Q3         Q4       2
```